# Show MBProgressHUD on iPhone app's splash screen while Core Data store is migrating to new version?

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen, mbprogresshud

If my iPhone app needs to update the Core Data database, I would like to show an [MBProgressHUD](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MBProgressHUD) view to users while my iPhone app is loading, so they know that it's working and not hanging. How might I go about adding an MBProgressHUD to the splash screen while the data store is migrating? Normally I would attach it to the UIViewController's view, but the splash screen is under the app delegate. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible to overlay anything over the splash screen as it's static.

You could, however, delay the intensive process for a bit until the app loads, then create a fake splash screen with the progress indicator while the intensive stuff goes on in a background thread.

Comment: Is there a best practice for how to do this?

Comment: I can't give specifics, as I haven't done this before.  However, I would just assume that you should do what Alex said below, namely wait until `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is called, and in that method (it's in your Delegate) create a view controller and display it as a modal view, then start your backgrounding thread.  Once that's finished, make it so that it sends a callback to your delegate, and in that delegate method remove the loading view.  So basically you're just adding a view in your delegate method, and dismissing it when the background process is done.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `#define` macro in your application delegate header file (or in a "globals" header), like so:

```
#define MyAppDelegate [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

Then, when you want access the application delegate property, you can do so like this anywhere in your application you have imported that header (or the globals header):

```
MyAppDelegate.property = foo;
[[MyAppDelegate property] bar];
```

This may help you manage your progress view at any point in the app's life.

**EDIT**

*sudo rm -rf* is correct that you can't do work during the splash screen. But you can start your progress view in the app delegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, and then launch work on a background thread. Once your background thread's work is finished, have a callback dismiss the progress view.